# Can I configure Eclipse to run my Android app project when I run from my Android library?

Tags: android, eclipse

When I'm editing files in my Android library and Run/Debug, it wants to launch the library.  I would like it to launch the Android Application (which is another project in my workspace).

I have three projects in my workspace: library, full app, lite app.  The full and lite apps are just wrappers around the library to allow me to build the two versions.

Thanks!
Will

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just right click on the project you want to run and run it

Or open a class in the project you want to run and click run

Or sometimes it works by selecting the folder of the project (in package explorer) and then clicking run

Comment: That does work.  I was just hoping that there was a way to tell Eclipse that it should run the app when I run from the library.  Open Declaration and debugging automatically open the files found in the library, so I need to switch back to the app using the mouse.  It's not a huge problem, but I just figured there might be a way.

Also, the source for my library no longer shows up under my project in LIBRARY_src.  I'm not sure what I did to cause that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Accept answer? Also once you run the application the first time you can press the down arrow next to the run button and the application should be there, just click on it there

Comment: Is there any way to run that application that appears in dropdown with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: You can configure shortcuts by going (In Juno) by going window, preferences, general, keys, and then find "Run Android Application" Eclipse is pre configured to use Alt-Shift-A, R, this means press Alt-Shift-A and then press R or select run from the list in the bottom right corner